# exit() or _exit()?

Tags: c

Consider this snippet of code:

```
void do_child(void);

int main(void){
int n;
pid_t child;
printf("Write a number: ");
scanf("%d", &n);
if(n != 1){
exit(1);
}
child = fork();
if(child >= 0){ /* fork ok */
 if(child == 0){
    printf("Child pid: %d\n", getpid());
    do_child();
    _exit(0);
  }
 else{ /* parent */
    printf("Child parent: %d\n", getpid());
    _exit(0);
 }
}
else{ /* fallito */
    perror("No fork");
    return 1;
}
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void do_child(void){
/* some code here */
if(1 != 1){
    /* what to write here?? _exit or exit*/
}   
}
```

When exiting from a child process it is best to write `_exit` instead of `exit` but if i need to call an external function and into this function i want to put an exit, what should i write? `_exit` or `exit`?

Comment: Every process is somebody's child (except the process with id 1), there's no sense in to chosing `_exit` over `exit` based on that.

Comment: Who says that "it is best to write `_exit` instead of `exit`"?

Comment: @KerrekSB http://www.unixguide.net/unix/programming/1.1.3.shtml

Comment: That page is wrong about everything.

Comment: @n.m. LOL :D i don't know what to say...i'm a n00b! xD can you explain me why please??

Comment: It's very out-of-date! Ignore all the stuff about vfork and affecting the parent with calls in the child; that's historical nonsense. stdio buffering: well, he has a point there, but it's not that common to have stuff in the buffers when you're forking (forking halfway through printing a line? possible...). If it's a problem, just flush.

Comment: I think ironically the references to C++ being the "most problematic" are the most out: you _want_ destructors to be called! The child inherits all the parent's objects and file descriptors, and _should_ perform cleanup. Recommending _exit is historical and goes against best practices now.

Comment: @NicholasWilson, it very much depends on the destructors themselves. E.g. if a destructor cleans up a temporary file or otherwise destroys a resource used by the other process as well, then running these prematurely might be bad indeed. The kernel can clean up stuff like file descriptors just fine on `_exit` without needing destructors for that.

Comment: It depends on what's on the other end of the fd: something you need to send a close message to? My feeling is that the situations where you might prefer `_exit` are more the special cases, and `exit` really should be the normal action. I'd be more inclined to explicitly release resources like connections or temp files, and perhaps even suggest that using `_exit` feels a bit hacky? It's a matter of perspective, maybe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can expect [`exit`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exit) to call functions registered with [`atexit`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atexit). [`_exit`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/_exit) won't do that. Normally, each registered cleanup handler should be executed exactly once, usually in the process in which it was registered. This means that a child process should `_exit()` and the parent should `exit()`. If the child process does [`exec`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec) some other program, which is probably the most common case, then that new program will overwrite any registered handlers, which means that you are back to `exit()`.

As to external functions: I'd say you should call `exit` but you should be prepared to encounter strange behaviour if the parent registers non-trivial stuff `atexit` before doing the fork. So try to fork early unless you mean to `exec` in the child. And have an eye on what exit handlers your own code and the libraries you use might install. I/O buffer flushing is one example.

Answer (score 3):

*`exit()`* terminates after cleanup whereas *`_exit()`* terminates immediately.

I would suggest that under normal circumstances, *`exit()`* is the correct approach - although I am sure you will understand what you are doing if you chose *`_exit()`*?!

I'll cite [MSDN online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wdz5232.aspx) as it's in my favourites :)

Comment: LOL :D i don't understand anything xD here's it says that it is dangerous to terminate a child process without _Exit: http://www.unixguide.net/unix/programming/1.1.3.shtml

Comment: Ummm... looks like I've been very lucky over the years, as I seldom (if ever) use _exit() - and I've not noticed the problems he's suggesting!