# how child processes get terminated when use execve loader in C

Tags: c, linux, process

I'm a beginner in C and I'm struggling in understanding the `execve` function in C to invoke a child process to loads and runs the executable object file.

We know that `execve` returns to the calling program only if there is an error such as not being able to find filename, so it is called once and never returns.

Here is my question, if we fork a child process to call `execve` but since `execve` never return, it will be always executing something if everything is OK, which means that the child process will never get terminated, so how can parent process reap this child process? below is sample code

```
if ((pid = Fork()) == 0) { /* Child runs user job */
   if (execve(argv[0], argv, environ) < 0) {      -------->line 2
      printf("%s: Command not found.\n", argv[0]);
      exit(0);
   }
}

/* Parent waits for foreground job to terminate */
if (waitpid(pid, &status, 0) < 0) {  ------------> but the child process never terminated
   printf("waitpid error");
}
```

so in line 2, `execve(argv[0], argv, environ)` never return, so the child process is never terminated?

Comment: The child process will be terminated when the program you load terminates the process (by returning from its `main` function or by calling `exit`). Just like any other process.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thank u now I see. but why the execve is designed to never return? can't we design it like : return 1 if the child process is terminated?

Comment: For that you have to ask the original designers of UNIX. As for knowing when the child-process terminates (and possibly get its return code) use e.g. [`wait`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html).

Comment: @amjad It can’t return 1 if the child process is terminated because it IS the child process. Once `exec` succeeds, your code is no longer running, and there is nothing to return to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program `foo`, will start some child process to run some other program, `bar`,
and you want it to do this with the basic system calls `fork` and `execve`

Let's call your initial `foo` process *p1*. (This stands for some [pid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier).)

First, you will call [fork](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html).
That creates a child process of *p1* that is running *another instance* of `foo`
Call that child process *p1.1*.

*p1.1* is running `foo`. But you want to run `bar`. So immediately in *p1.1*, `foo` calls [`execve(path/to/bar ...)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/execve).
This replaces the instance of `foo` that *p1.1* is running with an instance of `bar`. Then your
child process *p1.1* is running `bar`, as you want.

**Be clear about this**:-

`execve(path/to/bar ...)` does *not* start `bar` in a new sub-process of
*p1.1*, and leave *p1.1* still running the post-fork instance of `foo`.  Instead, `execve(path/to/bar ...)` *replaces*
that instance of `foo` with an instance of `bar` in process *p1.1*. After `fork`, but before `execve`,
we have:

```
p1[foo] -> p1.1[foo]
```

And after `execve` we have:

```
p1[foo] -> p1.1[bar]
```

not:

```
p1[foo] -> p1.1[foo] -> p1.1.1[bar]
```

You can see then that `execve` *cannot* return *success* to its caller, *p1.1*[foo],
because if `execve` succeeds, then *p1.1*[foo] *no longer exists*.
And of course `execve` cannot return success to *p1*[foo], because *p1*[foo] *did not call it*.

> since execve never return, it will be always executing something if everything is OK

No. `execve` replaces *p1.1*[foo] with *p1.1*[bar] and does not return, because the caller no longer exists. Then *p1.1*[bar] runs until it terminates.

*p1.1*[bar] will terminate sooner or later in one of the ways
that *any* program terminates: it will run until a normal `exit`, or it will
be killed by a signal, or it might possibly call `abort` of its own volition.

How can the parent process (*p1*) reap this child process (*p1.1*)?

Firstly, *it doesn't have to*. Once *p1*[foo] has started *p1.1*, it could,
if that's what you want, just forget about *p1.1*, get on with other business
if it has any, and eventually `exit`. If *p1* terminates before *p1.1*, then *p1.1*
becomes an [*orphan process*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphan_process).
An orphan process is immediately adopted as a child by the [`init` process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init). So
if nothing terminates it in the meantime, *p1.1* will be reaped when `init` terminates, in system shutdown.

But very likely, you don't want to abandon orphans and you *do* want `foo` to know the exit status of the child `bar`. In that case,
*p1*[foo] must sooner or later call [wait/waitpid](https://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid) to learn now *p1.1*
ended, and then act accordingly.

In the meantime, *p1*[foo] may well be communicating with *p1.1*[bar] using some
form of [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). And/or *p1*[foo] might
be noting the elapsed time while *p1.1*[bar] still has not ended. In one of these ways, or others, *p1*[foo] might determine
that *p1.1*[bar] is in trouble, has gone on for too long, and decide to [kill](https://linux.die.net/man/3/kill) *p1.1* itself.
When *p1.1* gets killed - whoever does it - or ends by its own volition, `wait/waitpid` will return that information to *p1*[foo], and then it
may exit itself, or carry on doing something else.

In a comment you enquired:

> can't we design [`execve`] like : return 1 if the child process is terminated?

A system call like that can certainly be designed, and already exists, but it cannot
be a *non-blocking system call that replaces the calling process*, which is what `execve`
is. It would be a *blocking system call that runs a sub-process of the calling
process and returns the sub-process's exit status to the parent*. The one that does that is [`system`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/system)

Comment: Hi could you also look at this question, please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53331232/how-can-i-shell-have-more-than-one-job-in-linux

Answer (score 0):

From man page of [execve](https://linux.die.net/man/2/execve):

> On success, execve() does not return, on error -1 is returned, and
>   errno is set appropriately.

To receive return value from child process, need to use [wait](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html)

Comment: can u explain how a child process get terminated?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239645/exit-from-a-child-process-c

Answer (score 0):

In the simple case, the child process will eventually terminate whether or not you call `exec` successfully. So this is easy… just have the parent `wait` for every child it creates with `fork`.

However, there is a technique to propagate failures from `exec` to the parent. The technique works like this:

1. Create a pipe.
2. Fork.
3. In the child process, close the read side of the pipe. Mark the write side as close-on-exec.
4. Call `exec` in the child. If it fails, write a failure message to the pipe, and exit.
5. From the parent process, close the write end of the pipe and read from the read end.

If `exec` succeeds, the parent process will read no data and just get EOF. If it fails, the parent will read the error message.